# Xcode 5 iOS app not using correct product name for build id

Tags: ios, xcode5, build-settings, bundle-identifier

I am having some issues with the build id for my App.

I have two builds set up, `Debug` and `Release`. I've already created two schemes `App-debug` and `App-release`.

`App-debug` is set to use the `Debug` configuration and `app-release` the `Release` config. In my `build settings` I've set the `Product Name` field to `appStaging` and `appPublish` for the `Debug` and `Release` build configurations respectively.

However, the `build identifier` field gets set to `appPublish` even when I've selected the `app-debug` scheme. I am not sure why, but it is affecting my ability to archive the product correctly. What am I missing?

It seems that if I run a product clean, close xcode and reopen it, the `bundle identifier` shows up correctly in the target info. However, when I run a `Product -> Archive` something happens and it builds for `appPublish` and after, the `build identifier` displays the wrong name. Still no idea why this is happening though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured out the reason -- each scheme has a separate section for the `Archive` settings that is separate from the `Run` settings. I missed this earlier, which is why I kept running into this issue.